# Is there a wordpress plugin for live NOTAMs?

Tags: notam, website

How can I embed live notams to my wordpress webiste?
Is there a plugin to get live NOTAMs updates on my website?

Comment: Why do your tags have nothing to do with NOTAMs?

Comment: This question is fundamentally about web programming; the fact that the data desired is related to aviation is fairly incidental.  This question would best be posed to a discussion board specializing in WordPress and how to do things like you want there.

Comment: I'm also not entirely sure why you'd want to do this, unless it's just for fun/practice, since anyone looking for NOTAMs would want to consult an official source to make sure they're seeing up-to-date valid information instead of someone's wordpress site.

Comment: Migrate this to stack overflow and you should get a decent response

Comment: @Cloud he won't get help on Stack Overflow - the community at SO is happy to help people who have shown research effort and are struggling with programming issues. And last but not least, questions about plugins, libraries and other external resources are off-topic at SO as stated in https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo It's why I gave up there a long time ago.. one of the most useless SE sites

Comment: @Cloud not really true. It's just not a replacement for Google search.

Comment: People on SO are surprisingly helpful if you say a) here is what I’m trying to do, b) *here is what I tried*, c) here is the error I’m getting or what is happening instead of what I want to happen. When it is evident from the question that the OP hasn’t even done a Google search then people tend to be less helpful. You have to at least show effort.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, this is off-topic and more related to understanding APIs and Wordpress plug-ins.

If you want a place to start:
https://developer.laminardata.aero/documentation/notamdata might give you API access, but you'll have to build it yourself which is beyond the scope of this site.

As @Zach Lipton mentioned in the comments, even the official sites have a disclaimer, but here are a couple official sites you could check out:

- https://notams.aim.faa.gov/notamSearch/nsapp.html#/
- https://www.notams.faa.gov/dinsQueryWeb/

Somewhat related: [Is there a Flights API to get flight information months in advance?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/7959/is-there-a-flights-api-to-get-flight-information-months-in-advance/7961#7961)

Comment: If he is asking about out-the-box plugins, I doubt he is a developer. But good answer, anyway. I suggest this be migrated to SO.